# Can _netrc handle passphrases with spaces?

Tags: git, .netrc

The following configuration works:

```
machine code.mycompany.net
login supernerd
password HelloW0rld
```

The following configuration doesn't work:

```
machine code.mycompany.net
login supernerd
password Please excuse my dear aunt sally.
```

Comment: Put quotes around the password.

Comment: @runrig And how to store a password with a space and a quote?

Comment: @ceving the only problem would be if the password had both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue557704) or [this page](http://www.gnus.org/distribution.html), spaces in password don't seem to be supported in a `.netrc (`or `_netrc`) file.
Or even if they are, not all the programs using that `.netrc` file will be able to interpret said space correctly.

---

As [runrig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10415/runrig) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674888/can-netrc-handle-passphrases-with-spaces/12675195?noredirect=1#comment45821702_12675195):

> Quoting the field as in another answer here should work, but the python library doesn't like it.
>   But, e.g., command line `ftp` and the `perl netrc` library is fine with it.

So this should work when used when those commands:

```
password "Please excuse my dear aunt sally."
```

Comment: The man page doesn't mention spaces when used that way in a netrc file: http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc

Comment: The python netrc library doesn't support spaces, but should. It's a bug in the library. Quoting the field as in another answer here should work, but the python library doesn't like it. But, e.g., command line ftp and the perl netrc library is fine with it.

Answer (score 4):

Using ftp on IRIX 6.5 running on an SGI, I added quotes around my password and it works fine, e.g.:

```
password "Please excuse my dear aunt sally."
```

Comment: git (v1.9.5) does not understand quoted passwords containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is the tokenizer of the [GNU Inetutils](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/inetutils.git/tree/ftp/ruserpass.c) version 2.5:

```c
token (void)
{
  char *cp;
  int c;
  struct toktab *t;

  if (feof (cfile) || ferror (cfile))
    return (0);
  while ((c = getc (cfile)) != EOF &&
         (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ' || c == ','))
    continue;
  if (c == EOF)
    return (0);
  cp = tokval;
  if (c == '"')
    {
      while ((c = getc (cfile)) != EOF && c != '"')
        {
          if (c == '\\')
            c = getc (cfile);
          *cp++ = c;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      *cp++ = c;
      while ((c = getc (cfile)) != EOF
             && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != ' ' && c != ',')
        {
          if (c == '\\')
            c = getc (cfile);
          *cp++ = c;
        }
    }
  *cp = 0;
  if (tokval[0] == 0)
    return (0);
  for (t = toktab; t->tokstr; t++)
    if (!strcmp (t->tokstr, tokval))
      return (t->tval);
  return (ID);
}
```

As you can see: tokens may be surrounded by double quotes.

```c
  if (c == '"')
    {
      while ((c = getc (cfile)) != EOF && c != '"')
        {
          if (c == '\\')
            c = getc (cfile);
          *cp++ = c;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have studied wget's netrc.c; I hope most netrc parsers work similarly:

Note that `#` after whitespace starts a comment until end of line.

A string can be put between double quotes (for example if the string starts
with `#`, or contains a lot of whitespace that we don't want to backslash).

```
"#pass%"
"S3cret with spaces"
```

To make sure a character is understood as part of a string, prefix it
with a backslash so that it is understood verbatim.  This is supported
with or without double quotes:

```
S3cret\ with\ spaces
\#not-a-comment
backslash:\\
"anything"
"double\"quote"
```